# How to install php_java extension in wamp?

Tags: php-java-bridge

I have tried this in my php.ini file:

extension=php_java.dll

```
[java]
java.java = “C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/javaw.exe”
java.java_home = “C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7”
java.class.path = “G:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.9/ext/JavaBridge.jar”
java.library = “C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client/jvm.dll”
java.library.path = “G:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.9/ext;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib”
```

Now WAMP shows php_java extention, but php_info() does not shows java configurations.

Comment: Take a look at this [web page](http://www.developer.com/java/other/php-with-java-using-php-java-bridge-tutorial.html)

Answer (score -3):

use [phpjavabridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/) to make communication between PHP and Java.

I have a youtube vid in French on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHtgPrFOChQ

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you're going to provide a link in an answer, make sure that your answer can stand on its own if the link was to die out or get removed.